# Query executer - Start of upper step is not overlap with end of lower step

Tags: postgresql

I look on a Postgres query plan and I noticed that the upper step start time is not overlap with the lower step end time, so I wonder where the gap time is spent?

fields name were edited for this query.

As you can see below the query executer has 2 steps.
The lower step 'Index Scan' end at 5730.776 (actual time), but the root step begin on 19199.316 (actual time). My question is what was happened between 5730.776 to 19199.316 ?

postgres 9.1

```
explain analyze select a_id,b_id,c_id,d_id,e_id,mydate, f,sum(used) used
from report A where mydate >= '2013-05-01' and mydate  <= '2013-08-30'
group by a_id,b_id,c_id,d_id,e_id,date,f;
                                                                                                      QUERY PLAN
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 HashAggregate  (cost=412378.59..418074.28 rows=569569 width=70) (actual time=**19199.316**..25518.672 rows=4935988 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan using report_dateonly_idx on report a  (cost=0.00..298464.83 rows=5695688 width=70) (actual time=0.033..**5730.776** rows=5816028 loops=1)
         Index Cond: ((date >= '2013-05-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (date <= '2013-08-30 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
 Total runtime: 29148.500 ms
```

Comment: you are comparing a date(literal) to a timestamp. The parser/planner promotes your date(literal) to a timestamp. This promotion involves adding '00:00:00' to the date(literal). Instead you could promote ("_cast_") the timestamp _down_ to a `date`. BTW: don't give columns the name "date". `date` is a reserved word (type name)

Comment: @wildplasser I think this should be an answer, it would be nice if you also add some link to type priorities in PostgreSQL

Comment: @wildplasser, i am deeply sorry that i wasnt able to explain my question in the correct way. I am not question about the date in my query. My question is about the planner times. I will edit my query.

Comment: It appears the contrucion of the hash table takes about 3.5 times the time as the actual index scan (19199.316 / 5730.776). I think this is caused by the hashtable needing to be resized and/or spoilt to disk. There is an option (BUFFERS=1 ? ... _not sure_) for the explain analyze statement to monitor this behaviour. BTW: there is a good chance that an index-only aggregation will be less costly; setting `work_mem` _lower_ and `random_page_cost` _lower_ ( ~1.2 ) could cause this kind of plan to be used.

Comment: BTW2: the observed behaviour could also be caused by swapping (if memory is over committed e.g if `work_mem * active_sessions` is larger than available physical memory. BTW3: the amount of distinct values is almost as large as the actual row count (4M /5M) it could be that your statistics are off or absent.

Comment: @wildplasser this is an Amazon ssd machine (64gig ram) , so swap is not the problem. I think the problem is CPU utilization. It seems that   postgres work with single cpu for aggregation.

Comment: Postgres is single threaded. Multiple CPUs can only be employed for other tasks (or system tasks, such as pagefaulting) And CPU is _not_ your problem, IMHO.

Comment: The CPU is 100% during aggregation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be interested in [this series of blog posts on understanding query plans](http://www.depesz.com/2013/04/16/explaining-the-unexplainable/).

In your case, you are misinterpreting what the two numbers in each cost/timing represent. They are not the start and end of the operation, but (roughly) the cost/time *before the first row*, and the cost/time *including all rows*.

Depesz gives the example of a sort operation having "cost=22.88..23.61" - the cost to prepare the data is high, because you have to sort everything before you can return any of it; the cost of actually returning it is much lower, because it's just spooling through your sorted list.

So in your example the 19199.316 doesn't mean that the HashAggregate doesn't start running until t=19199.316, it means that until t=19199.316 no data will come out of the HashAggregate because it is still preparing stuff.

In fact, the HashAggregate will start *processing* data as soon as the Index Scan starts returning it, which is at t=0.033; by t=5730.776, the Index Scan has found all the relevant rows, but the HashAggregate is still processing them. At t=19199.316, the HashAggregate is ready to start returning data to its parent (which in this case is the final result), and at t=25518.672, it's finished returning them.

Depezs also has a tool which interprets query plans into a table form; [here's your plan](http://explain.depesz.com/s/V6Zm). Note that the HashAggregate shows an "exclusive time" of 19787.896 - that's how long it took to do the hashing, ignoring where the input data came from.

Comment: It seems strange that aggregator start processing at 5sec and it took 15 sec to return first row. and 5 sec to return all rows. aggregator need to process all data in order to return result so first row and all rows need to be almost the same.

Comment: @AvihaiMarchiano I wondered that, but then I noticed this: "rows=4935988" That's a lot of rows, even after aggregation! Also, and this is speculation, it might have done the "hash" part of its job but not the "aggregate" part: it's worked out how the rows fit into groups, but not the sum within each of those groups.

Answer (score 1):

The **reason** for the observed behaviour: your statistics are wrong:

```
HashAggregate  (cost=412378.59..418074.28 rows=569569 width=70) (actual time=**19199.316**..25518.672 rows=4935988 loops=1)
 [expected] -----------------------------------^^^^^^       [actual rows found] > ------------------------ ^^^^^^^
```

This is off by a factor nine, and causes the planner to choose a hash-table based aggregation, since it thinks that the result will fit into work_mem. It is initially undersized, needs to be resized a few times and if does not fit into workmem it even has to be spilt to disk.

BTW: I was unable to recreate this kind of plan. I keep getting bitmap index scans.

Comment: I have 64GIG ram , so i dont see any need to split to disk. Do you have any advice to do this better?